# R - Adding vectors/matix as row to another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, error-handling, rbind

I thought I already mastered that skill a long time ago, but in this case I am clueless, I am only getting error messages.

This is the same question, but it doesnt work for me!
[How to add a named vector as a row to a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581122/how-to-add-a-named-vector-as-a-row-to-a-data-frame)

I have this dataframe:

```
structure(list(AT2VI12 = 28, DENI011 = 27, GB0033R = 0, SE0004A = 2, 
SE0013R = 4), .Names = c("AT2VI12", "DENI011", "GB0033R", 
"SE0004A", "SE0013R"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")

>df
    AT2VI12 DENI011 GB0033R SE0004A SE0013R
1      28      27       0       2       4
```

Now I want to add the 2nd column of this tiny 2nd dataframe.

```
structure(list(x = c("AT2VI12", "DENI011", "GB0033R", "SE0004A", 
"SE0013R"), n = c(17L, 35L, 2L, 14L, 5L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("x", "n"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

>df2
       x     n
    <chr> <int>
1 AT2VI12    17
2 DENI011    35
3 GB0033R     2
4 SE0004A    14
5 SE0013R     5
```

I did this:

```
df <- rbind(df, df2[,2])  # Error message: Not the same number of columns
```

Then I tried this (wanted to delete the additional row later)

```
df2 = t(df2)
df <- rbind(df, df2[2,]) # Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi))
```

And this:

```
rbind(df, as.data.frame(t(df2)))
```

I dont know whats wrong. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `tibble` and whichever indexing you will use, it will always return a `tibble` so you need to unlist it to get a vector:

```
 rbind(df,unlist(df2[2]))
  AT2VI12 DENI011 GB0033R SE0004A SE0013R
1      28      27       0       2       4
2      17      35       2      14       5
```