# Add new row for the result of a simple equation using row groups in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am having trouble with this simple task.

In the following `data.frame`, how can I add an extra row containing the result of `Sepal.Length*0.75 + Sepal.Width*0.25` for each column? Thank you

```
as.data.frame(t(iris[1:5,1:4]))
               1   2   3   4   5
Sepal.Length 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0
Sepal.Width  3.5 3.0 3.2 3.1 3.6
Petal.Length 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4
Petal.Width  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
```

Comment: When you take the transpose, it is converted to a `matrix` and matrix can hold only a single class.  Possibly you need need to get the calculation done before the transpose

Comment: @akrun see edit :)

Comment: It's easier to add named columns in data.frame than rows, and again grouping is usually done by row, not by column. Why make your life harder for no reason? Are you sure you really want a row? (As corroboration [How to add a named vector as a row to a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581122/how-to-add-a-named-vector-as-a-row-to-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to create a column before the transpose as `t` will convert to a `matrix` and `matrix` can hold only single `class`.  As the fifth column of 'iris' is not 'numeric', while doing the transpose, the whole `matrix` convert to `character`.  So, instead of doing the calculation afterwards, do it before the transpose

```
df1 <- iris[1:5,]
df1$new <- with(df1, Sepal.Length * 0.75 + Sepal.Width *25)
t(df1)
```

#### Update

Based on the updated structure, we subset the row of the matrix 'm1' based on the row names, do the calculation and `rbind` with the original matrix

```
m1 <- as.data.frame(t(iris[1:5,1:4]))
m2 <- rbind(m1, new = m1["Sepal.Length",] * 0.75 + m1["Sepal.Width", ] * 0.25)
m2
#              1     2     3     4    5
#Sepal.Length 5.1 4.900 4.700 4.600 5.00
#Sepal.Width  3.5 3.000 3.200 3.100 3.60
#Petal.Length 1.4 1.400 1.300 1.500 1.40
#Petal.Width  0.2 0.200 0.200 0.200 0.20
#new          4.7 4.425 4.325 4.225 4.65
```

Answer (score 3):

Answer from @akrun seems the best one, yet if you want to work with your final dataset only, you can use row references -

```
x <- as.data.frame(t(iris[1:5,1:4]))
x[c('new'),] <- x[c('Sepal.Length'), ]*0.75 + x[c('Sepal.Width'), ]*0.25
```